# Split a string containing hex into seperate values

Tags: python, string, list, split, hex

I have strings of hex like this:

```
s = "\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xefn\x15\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xf2\x00\x00\x00\xf2\x00"
```

and I want to get a list of the separate values, like

`['\x08', '\x00', etc]` or `['08', '00', '00', etc]`

My attempts to `s.split()` the string have failed

`s.split('\x')` results in `ValueError: invalid \x escape`

`s.split('\\x')` results in
 `['\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xefn\x15\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xf2\x00\x00\x00\xf2\x00']`

Any attempts to iterate through the string and covert each 'character' to an int or anything other than a str(which result in mostly 'blank' characters) has failed with errors. Can anyone suggest a way to get the desired results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `\xhh` item is **one** byte in the string.

Python is displaying a string *representation*, which is a string literal notation that can safely be copied and pasted into any ASCII context to rebuild the same value.

As such, any non-ASCII codepoint is represented by an escape sequence, with the vast majority of these represented by `\xhh` hex escapes. You'll notice that tab characters use the `\t` escape sequence, for example. There are no actual `\` or `x` characters in your string, so you can't split on `'\\x'` either.

You can convert this to a list of individual characters by just passing the string to `list()`:

```
>>> s = "\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xefn\x15\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xf2\x00\x00\x00\xf2\x00"
>>> list(s)
['\x08', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xef', 'n', '\x15', '\x01', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x10', '\x02', 'l', '\t', '\xa0', '\x00', '\xf2', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xf2', '\x00']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xefn\x15\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02l\t\xa0\x00\xf2\x00\x00\x00\xf2\x00"

print(list(bytearray(s)))
[8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 239, 110, 21, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 2, 108, 9, 160, 0, 242, 0, 0, 0, 242, 0]
```

Comment: Why the bytearray?

Comment: Because I presumed the OP wanted ints,i.e *Any attempts to iterate through the string and covert each 'character' to an int*, obvioulsy they can just call list if they don't

Comment: I think that that was an attempt at getting the desired output. We'll see! :-)